# sum of each row and column

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to calculates the sum of each row and column of a matrix.

Given an NxN matrix `mm`, is there a way to linearize the following code?

```
for jj=1:N
  sm(jj)=sum(mm(jj,:)) + sum(mm(:,jj));
end
sm = sm - diag(mm)';
```

As an example:

```
mm=[1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]

mm =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


for jj=1:3
  sm(jj)=sum(mm(jj,:)) + sum(mm(:,jj));
end
sm=sm-diag(mm)'

sm =

     8    10    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize this by using the second input of `sum` to specify the dimension along which to perform the summation.

```
% Sum columns  Sum rows     diagonal
sum(mm, 1).' + sum(mm, 2) - diag(mm)

%    8
%   10
%   12
```